# Should a browser extension change the User-Agent header for requests it initiates?

Tags: http, header, user-agent, browser-extension

We are developing a browser extension which, as part of its feature set, connects to an external API (on our servers) to load data.

For a few reasons, it's useful to know which version of the extension is connecting to the API. It can be useful to track upgrade rates between versions, but on a less tinfoil-hat note we may need to respond to APIs differently based on observed bugs in older versions of the extension.

What's the best way for the extension to let the server know what version it is running?

1. Add the information to the existing User-Agent header? (i.e. this request is being sent from my extension inside this browser)
   `User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (…) Firefox/3.6.3 (MyPlugin/1.2.3.2256)`
2. Completely replace the User-Agent header? (i.e. this request is being sent from the extension, and since it's not being rendered by the browser the original UA string doesn't matter)
   `User-Agent: MyPlugin/1.2.3.2256`
3. Add a separate header to the request just to track this information? (i.e. this request is still being sent from the extension's host browser, but also here's some extra information for you)
   `User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (…) Firefox/3.6.3`
   `X-MyPlugin-Version: 1.2.3.2256`

Option 3 sounds a bit of a cop-out to me, because the specific purpose of the User-Agent header is to pass on information about the program making the request, but I don't know if there are any specific recommendations between the other two options

Comment: 4) include a `version=` in the request payload? - Are you using the browsers built-in http functionality? if so then I would say there is a case to be made that the browser *is* still the UA & 3 makes sense. If you *ever* want browser metrics e.g. to modify behaviour of the plugin running under different browser versions/builds then 2 is definitely out.

Comment: @AlexK I considered that option 4) but I don't want to highlight "plugin version number" as an input parameter, at best it's environment data.

Answer (score 0):

I think option 2.  The reason for this is that it isn't the browser making the request to the endpoint but your plugins code, which could be construed as a separate process.

Thinking ahead, what if your plugin was a standalone application or suchlike - it wouldn't then make sense to have some agents with one format, and some with others.

This is also assuming that any pertinent browser information you might need is in the plugin UA.